# get gradient using vector notation

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, gradient-descent

I don't get the part that how can we get the gradient w.r.t $z$ of $z^Ty, z^Tz, z^TAz$ and just $Az$ by using vector notation of

$z, y \in R^n$ and $A \in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$

Comment: For clarification: how are you defining the gradient? If it is the classical introductory definition of $$\nabla f = \left(\frac {\partial f}{\partial z_1}, \frac {\partial f}{\partial z_2}, ..., \frac {\partial f}{\partial z_n}\right)$$ then you do the calculation in coordinates because that is how your gradient is defined. Once you are done, then you can express the answer directly in terms of $y, z, A$. As for your last one, the gradient is defined for functions into $\Bbb R$, which $f(z) = Az$ is not. That map into $\Bbb R^n$, so the gradient is not defined for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write the functions more explicitly and then so how it turns out:
$$
z^Ty=\sum_{i=1}^mz_iy_i \\
z^Tz=\sum_{i=1}^mz_iz_i=\sum_{i=1}^mz_i^2 \\
z^TAz=\sum_{i,j=1}^mz_ja_{ij}z_i
$$
For the last one, we will use the product rule anyway.
Now you can differentiate with respect to $z_k$ and see that:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}z^Ty=y_k \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}z^Tz=2z_k
$$
For the last one, we will apply the product rule:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}z^TAz=\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=1}^mz_ja_{ij}z_i=\sum_{j=1}^m z_ja_{kj} + \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ik}z_i
$$
Overall, you will get:
$$
\nabla z^Ty=y \\
\nabla z^Tz=2z \\
\nabla z^TAz=(A^T+A)z
$$
The function $z \to Az$ has no gradient, but the Jacobian Matrix equals $A$

Comment: minor notational quibble: you should have $\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}$ everywhere instead of $\frac{d}{dz_k}$. It may seem unimportant, but the definition of  $\frac{d}{dz_k}$ depends only on $z_k$ (other than identifying the point where the derivative is being taken), while the definition of $\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k}$ depends on all of the $z_i$. If you chose another orthonormal basis for $\Bbb R^n$ that happened to include the same $e_k$ vector, the value of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_k}$ would change, while $\frac{d f}{d z_k}$ would not.

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate your help @F. Conrad

Comment: that is so true thank you @PaulSinclair

Comment: Edited the $\partial$ in instead of the "d". It was meant to be more of a proof squetch, rather than a full proof with all details etc. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @F.Conrad - I figured as much, but I'm always leery about such notation abuses in places where the less-well-informed could be misled by them. Though I considered it likely you would know why, I gave the explanation anyway for the sake of any readers who might not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you mean the entire calculation is to be done without resorting to coordinates, then we have to start with a definition of the gradient that is not with respect to coordinates. The normal introductory definition of $$\nabla f = \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_2}, ..., \frac{\partial f}{\partial z_n}\right)$$
is defined by coordinates, so any calculation with it is necessarily done by coordinates.

The coordinate-free definition of $\nabla f$ requires the definition of the directional derivative first: If $v \in \Bbb R^n$, then the directional derivative of $f$ at $z$ in the direction of $v$ is $$D_vf(z) := \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_0f(z + tv)$$
Then the gradient is defined to be the unique vector such that $$v\cdot \nabla f(z) = D_vf(z)$$for all vectors $v\in \Bbb R^n$.

So let's examine your problems:

- $f(z) = z\cdot y$.

Then $f(z + tv) = z\cdot y + tv\cdot y$, so $D_vf(z) = v\cdot y$. From which we see that $\nabla f = y$.

- $f(z) = z\cdot z$.

Then $f(z + tv) = z\cdot z + t(z \cdot v)  + t(v \cdot z) + t^2(v\cdot v)$, do $D_vf(z) = 2( v\cdot z) = v\cdot (2z)$, since $v\cdot z = z \cdot v$. Therefore $\nabla f = 2z$.

- $f(z) = z\cdot Az$.

Then $f(z + tv) = z\cdot z + t(z \cdot Av) + t(v \cdot Az) + t^2(v \cdot v)$. So $D_vf(z) = (z \cdot Av) + (v \cdot Az) = (A^Tz \cdot v) + (v \cdot Az) = v \cdot (A^Tz + Az)$. Therefore $\nabla f = (A^T + A)z$.

Comment: Thank you very much Paul for your edit and the reply, however what I want is to get a separate results of f z^(T)y, z^(T)z, z^(T)Az and Az by using the above vector notation

Comment: @Arvin This is the more mathematical and precise version using the definition for arbitrary coordinates. Depending on your needs, this one might be better.

Comment: Now I understand what you just did and it seems really precise thank you a lot Paul really appreciate it